# How to read the second and third line of csv as one line

Tags: excel, vba, csv

My Excel reads a CSV file to get data for a grid table.

```
"header", "header", "header", "header"
"value1", 
"value2", "value3", "value4" 
"value5", "value6", "value7", "value8"
"value9", "value10", "value11", "value12"
```

I want to read the second and third line of the CSV as the first row of the grid table.
Other lines are read one by one.

My code is:

```
Dim FileName As String, folder As String    
    folder = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    FileName = Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\*.csv")


    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables _
            .Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & folder & FileName, Destination:=ActiveCell)
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
            .TextFilePlatform = 850
            .TextFileStartRow = 1
            .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
            .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
            .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
            .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
            .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
            .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
            .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1)
            .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=True
        End With
```

My approach:
I am trying to modify the csv file with a new one that will have the second and third line merged as the second line.

```
filePath = folder & fileName
 
 Dim fName As String, fso As Object, fsoFile As Object, txt As Variant

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Set fsoFile = fso.OpenTextFile(filePath, 1)
    txt = fsoFile.ReadAll
    fsoFile.Close

    txt = Split(txt, vbNewLine)

    txt(2 - 1) = "some text with special characters like & Char(44) & and & Chr(10) & and so on"

    Set fsoFile = fso.OpenTextFile(filePath, 2)
    fsoFile.Write Join(txt, vbNewLine)
    fsoFile.Close
```

the problem is that the grid table displays the special characters as & Char(44) & and & Char(10) & inside the cells...

Comment: Your second line only has an entry in Column1.  If you use Power Query, you can `Transpose=>Merge the first two columns with Linefeed as the separator =>Transpose=>Use first row as headers`

Comment: I cant use Power Query

Comment: Why not?  You can edit your connection string to accomplish the same task.  What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: I am using Excel 2019.

Comment: I guess you are using Excel 2019 on a Mac. You should add that  to your question or tags as solutions for Windows may not work on a Mac. I think you'll have to write separate code to merge those first two lines, unless someone knows a method to do it within the QueryTable.Add method.

Comment: I am using Excel 2019 on Windows 10. Yes I think I have to modify the original csv with merged the two lines..

Comment: If you have **Windows** Excel 2019, then you should have Power Query.  It may be called `Get & Transform` on the Data Tab.

Comment: Is there even a way to determine that `"value2", "value3",..` actually belongs to that first line? I mean how would you know that? Looks to me that there are just errors in the data file, and you should send it back to whoever provided the data. Btw if you know what the actual format _should_ be (nr of columns, data types etc.) you could validate it with this plug-in to quickly list all error lines https://github.com/BdR76/CSVLint/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three methods for combining 2nd and 3rd lines

```vb
Sub merge23()

    Dim fso As Object, tsIn, tsOut
    Dim s As String
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")
    Set tsIn = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\temp\test.csv", 1)
    Set tsOut = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\temp\test1.csv", 1)
    
    ' method 1
    Do While tsIn.AtEndOfLine <> True
        s = tsIn.readline
        If tsIn.Line <> 3 Then
            s = s & vbCrLf
        End If
        tsOut.write s
    Loop
    tsIn.Close
    tsOut.Close
    
    ' method 2
    Set tsIn = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\temp\test.csv", 1)
    s = tsIn.readall
    tsIn.Close
    s = Replace(s, vbCrLf, "~#~#~", 1, 1) 'mark 1st crlf
    s = Replace(s, vbCrLf, "", 1, 1) ' replace 2nd
    s = Replace(s, "~#~#~", vbCrLf, 1, 1) ' replace 1st crlf
    Set tsOut = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\temp\test2.csv", 1)
    tsOut.writeline s
    
    ' method 3 regex
    Dim regex
    Set regex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With regex
       .Global = False
       .MultiLine = True
       .Pattern = "^(.*\r\n.*)\r\n" ' 2nd crlf
    End With
    
    Set tsIn = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\temp\test.csv", 1)
    s = tsIn.readall
    tsIn.Close
    
    Set tsOut = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\temp\test3.csv", 1)
    s = regex.Replace(s, "$1")
    tsOut.writeline s
    tsOut.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will study it carefully.